# Grouping and computing in mySQL database with ordering

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table with `n` rows of data (here `n = 14`):

```
id  |  a    |  b    |  c    |  d    |  e      -----> fields (id is the primary key)
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
0   |  a0   |  b0   |  c0   |  d0   |  e0
1   |  a1   |  b1   |  c1   |  d1   |  e1
2   |  a2   |  b2   |  c2   |  d2   |  e2
3   |  a3   |  b3   |  c3   |  d3   |  e3
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
4   |  a4   |  b4   |  c4   |  d4   |  e4
5   |  a5   |  b5   |  c5   |  d5   |  e5
6   |  a6   |  b6   |  c6   |  d6   |  e6
7   |  a7   |  b7   |  c7   |  d7   |  e7
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
8   |  a8   |  b8   |  c8   |  d8   |  e8
9   |  a9   |  b9   |  c9   |  d9   |  e9
10  |  a10  |  b10  |  c10  |  d10  |  e10
11  |  a11  |  b11  |  c11  |  d11  |  e11
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
12  |  a12  |  b12  |  c12  |  d12  |  e12
13  |  a13  |  b13  |  c13  |  d13  |  e13
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
```

Now consider `m = 4` (m could also have other +ve integer values).
I wand to group the data into `m` rows in ascending order of `id` and also to take the remainder of the rows as follows:

```
id  |  a    |  b    |  c    |  d    |  e
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
0   |  a0   |  b0   |  c0   |  d0   |  e0
1   |  a1   |  b1   |  c1   |  d1   |  e1
2   |  a2   |  b2   |  c2   |  d2   |  e2
3   |  a3   |  b3   |  c3   |  d3   |  e3
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
4   |  a4   |  b4   |  c4   |  d4   |  e4
5   |  a5   |  b5   |  c5   |  d5   |  e5
6   |  a6   |  b6   |  c6   |  d6   |  e6
7   |  a7   |  b7   |  c7   |  d7   |  e7
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
8   |  a8   |  b8   |  c8   |  d8   |  e8
9   |  a9   |  b9   |  c9   |  d9   |  e9
10  |  a10  |  b10  |  c10  |  d10  |  e10
11  |  a11  |  b11  |  c11  |  d11  |  e11
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
12  |  a12  |  b12  |  c12  |  d12  |  e12
13  |  a13  |  b13  |  c13  |  d13  |  e13
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
```

Then I want a query to get the following data:

```
idd  |  aa   |  bb             |  cc               |  dd   |  ee
+----+-------+-----------------+-------------------+-------+--------------+
0    |  a0   |  max(b0,..,b3)  |  min(c0,...,c3)   |  d3   |  (e0+...+e3)
1    |  a4   |  max(b4,..,b7)  |  min(c4,...,c7)   |  d7   |  (e4+...+e7)
2    |  a8   |  max(b8,..,b11) |  min(c8,...,c11)  |  d11  |  (e8+...+e11)
3    |  a12  |  max(b12,b13)   |  min(c12,c13)     |  d13  |  (e12+e13)
+----+-------+-----------------+-------------------+-------+--------------+
```

I am new to mySQL database (Ubuntu) and trying and Goggling for many days for a solution.
It will be very helpful if someone show me a mySQL query how to acheive that.

For `m = 5` the query should return the following data:

```
idd  |  aa   |  bb             |  cc               |  dd   |  ee
+----+-------+-----------------+-------------------+-------+--------------+
0    |  a0   |  max(b0,...,b4) |  min(c0,...,c4)   |  d4   |  (e0+...+e4)
1    |  a5   |  max(b5,...,b9) |  min(c5,...,c9)   |  d9   |  (e5+...+e9)
2    |  a10  |  max(b10,..,b13)|  min(c10,..,c13)  |  d13  |  (e10...+e13)
+----+-------+-----------------+-------------------+-------+--------------+
```

Thanks in advance . . .

Comment: Your question would have been slightly easier to answer if you provided actual data, instead of string place holders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an `id` column which behaves like a row number, to group in batches of 4 records you can just aggregate over the `id` divided by 4, truncated to a whole number.  To see how this would work, `id` values of 0 through and including 3 would have a group of 0, since dividing these values by 4 yields less than 1.  Similarly, the next four records, `id` values of 4 through to 7, would have a group of 1.

```
SELECT
    TRUNCATE(t1.id / 4, 0) AS idd,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.id = (SELECT MIN(t2.id) FROM yourTable t2
                           WHERE TRUNCATE(t2.id / 4, 0) = TRUNCATE(t1.id / 4, 0))
             THEN t1.a END) AS aa,
    MAX(t1.b) AS bb,
    MIN(t1.c) AS cc,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.id = (SELECT MAX(t2.id) FROM yourTable t2
                           WHERE TRUNCATE(t2.id / 4, 0) = TRUNCATE(t1.id / 4, 0))
             THEN t1.d END) AS dd,
    SUM(t1.e) AS ee
FROM yourTable t1
GROUP BY
    TRUNCATE(t1.id / 4, 0);
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But `MIN(a) AS aa` is not what I want. I want the first value of each group  i.e., I want `aa --> a0, a4, a8, a12` instead of the MIN values of the group. Similarly for bb i want the last row value of b in each group.

Comment: @iPD I updated my answer.  For obtaining the first and last of each group I used a correlated subquery.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I was struggling for many days. I verified your answer and will accept it. Thanks again.